# How to deserialize JSON (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1)

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

Upon serializing the JSON if shows an error like this one. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1)

This is my code on serializing json

```vb
Dim test As List(Of properties) = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of properties))(response)
e.Result = test
```

This is my json:

```json
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               174.886706,
               -37.018018
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "country_code":"nz",
            "housenumber":"34",
            "street":"Jellicoe Road",
            "country":"New Zealand",
            "county":"Auckland",
            "datasource":{
               "sourcename":"openaddresses",
               "attribution":"© OpenAddresses contributors",
               "license":"BSD-3-Clause License"
            },
            "state":"Auckland Region",
            "district":"Auckland",
            "city":"Manurewa",
            "lon":174.886706,
            "lat":-37.018018,
            "postcode":"2102",
            "formatted":"34 Jellicoe Road, Manurewa 2102, New Zealand",
            "address_line1":"34 Jellicoe Road",
            "address_line2":"Manurewa 2102, New Zealand",
            "timezone":{
               "name":"Pacific/Auckland",
               "offset_STD":"+12:00",
               "offset_STD_seconds":43200,
               "offset_DST":"+13:00",
               "offset_DST_seconds":46800,
               "abbreviation_STD":"NZST",
               "abbreviation_DST":"NZDT"
            },
            "plus_code":"4VJPXVJP+QM",
            "result_type":"building",
            "rank":{
               "popularity":2.4928992206144494,
               "confidence":0.95,
               "match_type":"full_match"
            },
            "place_id":"5158e542e55fdc654059a25ef0694e8242c0c00203e2034b6f70656e6164647265737365733a616464726573733a6e7a2f636f756e747279776964652d6164647265737365732d636f756e7472792e6373763a38643534333962376163366334306438"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               175.766901,
               -37.821629
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "country_code":"nz",
            "housenumber":"34",
            "street":"Jellicoe Road",
            "country":"New Zealand",
            "county":"Matamata-Piako",
            "datasource":{
               "sourcename":"openaddresses",
               "attribution":"© OpenAddresses contributors",
               "license":"BSD-3-Clause License"
            },
            "state":"Waikato Region",
            "city":"Matamata",
            "lon":175.766901,
            "lat":-37.821629,
            "formatted":"34 Jellicoe Road, Matamata, New Zealand",
            "address_line1":"34 Jellicoe Road",
            "address_line2":"Matamata, New Zealand",
            "county_code":"MP",
            "timezone":{
               "name":"Pacific/Auckland",
               "offset_STD":"+12:00",
               "offset_STD_seconds":43200,
               "offset_DST":"+13:00",
               "offset_DST_seconds":46800,
               "abbreviation_STD":"NZST",
               "abbreviation_DST":"NZDT"
            },
            "plus_code":"4VJQ5QH8+8Q",
            "plus_code_short":"H8+8Q Matamata, Matamata-Piako, New Zealand",
            "result_type":"building",
            "rank":{
               "popularity":0.6696517116786308,
               "confidence":0.95,
               "match_type":"full_match"
            },
            "place_id":"51a148f7738af8654059fc389a232be942c0c00203e2034b6f70656e6164647265737365733a616464726573733a6e7a2f636f756e747279776964652d6164647265737365732d636f756e7472792e6373763a33333631373562373065333363333362"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               174.743699,
               -36.728367
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "country_code":"nz",
            "housenumber":"34",
            "street":"Jellicoe Road",
            "country":"New Zealand",
            "county":"Auckland",
            "datasource":{
               "sourcename":"openaddresses",
               "attribution":"© OpenAddresses contributors",
               "license":"BSD-3-Clause License"
            },
            "state":"Auckland Region",
            "district":"Auckland",
            "city":"Murrays Bay",
            "lon":174.743699,
            "lat":-36.728367,
            "formatted":"34 Jellicoe Road, Murrays Bay, New Zealand",
            "address_line1":"34 Jellicoe Road",
            "address_line2":"Murrays Bay, New Zealand",
            "timezone":{
               "name":"Pacific/Auckland",
               "offset_STD":"+12:00",
               "offset_STD_seconds":43200,
               "offset_DST":"+13:00",
               "offset_DST_seconds":46800,
               "abbreviation_STD":"NZST",
               "abbreviation_DST":"NZDT"
            },
            "plus_code":"4VMP7PCV+MF",
            "plus_code_short":"CV+MF Murrays Bay, Auckland, New Zealand",
            "result_type":"building",
            "rank":{
               "popularity":1.6904873504878504,
               "confidence":0.95,
               "match_type":"full_match"
            },
            "place_id":"512c62d861ccd7654059293e3e213b5d42c0c00203e2034b6f70656e6164647265737365733a616464726573733a6e7a2f636f756e747279776964652d6164647265737365732d636f756e7472792e6373763a35626333633734313932613434303664"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               174.021665,
               -36.133486
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "country_code":"nz",
            "housenumber":"34",
            "street":"Jellicoe Road",
            "country":"New Zealand",
            "county":"Kaipara",
            "datasource":{
               "sourcename":"openaddresses",
               "attribution":"© OpenAddresses contributors",
               "license":"BSD-3-Clause License"
            },
            "state":"Northland Region",
            "city":"Ruawai",
            "lon":174.021665,
            "lat":-36.133486,
            "formatted":"34 Jellicoe Road, Ruawai, New Zealand",
            "address_line1":"34 Jellicoe Road",
            "address_line2":"Ruawai, New Zealand",
            "county_code":"KP",
            "timezone":{
               "name":"Pacific/Auckland",
               "offset_STD":"+12:00",
               "offset_STD_seconds":43200,
               "offset_DST":"+13:00",
               "offset_DST_seconds":46800,
               "abbreviation_STD":"NZST",
               "abbreviation_DST":"NZDT"
            },
            "plus_code":"4VMPV28C+JM",
            "result_type":"building",
            "rank":{
               "popularity":0.35600631140076516,
               "confidence":0.95,
               "match_type":"full_match"
            },
            "place_id":"51f94ecc7ab1c0654059a73cba11161142c0c00203e2034b6f70656e6164647265737365733a616464726573733a6e7a2f636f756e747279776964652d6164647265737365732d636f756e7472792e6373763a36636333363832386437663931623964"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               174.021564,
               -36.13336
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "country_code":"nz",
            "housenumber":"34A",
            "street":"Jellicoe Road",
            "country":"New Zealand",
            "county":"Kaipara",
            "datasource":{
               "sourcename":"openaddresses",
               "attribution":"© OpenAddresses contributors",
               "license":"BSD-3-Clause License"
            },
            "state":"Northland Region",
            "city":"Ruawai",
            "lon":174.021564,
            "lat":-36.13336,
            "formatted":"34A Jellicoe Road, Ruawai, New Zealand",
            "address_line1":"34A Jellicoe Road",
            "address_line2":"Ruawai, New Zealand",
            "county_code":"KP",
            "timezone":{
               "name":"Pacific/Auckland",
               "offset_STD":"+12:00",
               "offset_STD_seconds":43200,
               "offset_DST":"+13:00",
               "offset_DST_seconds":46800,
               "abbreviation_STD":"NZST",
               "abbreviation_DST":"NZDT"
            },
            "plus_code":"4VMPV28C+MJ",
            "result_type":"building",
            "rank":{
               "popularity":0.35600631140076516,
               "confidence":0.95,
               "match_type":"full_match"
            },
            "place_id":"51ac58fca6b0c06540591b4cc3f0111142c0c00203e2034b6f70656e6164647265737365733a616464726573733a6e7a2f636f756e747279776964652d6164647265737365732d636f756e7472792e6373763a36653039366639653964306338646336"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "text":"34C Jellicoe Road",
      "parsed":{
         "housenumber":"34c",
         "street":"jellicoe road",
         "expected_type":"building"
      }
   }
}
```

And this is my model:

```vb
Public Class AutoCompleteResponse
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property features As String
    Public Property Properties As IList(Of properties)
End Class

Public Class properties
    'Public Property place_id As String

    Public Property country_code As String
    Public Property housenumber As String

    Public Property street As String

    Public Property country As String

    Public Property county As String

    Public Property state As String
    Public Property district As String
    Public Property city As String

    Public Property lon As String
    Public Property lat As String

    Public Property postcode As String

    Public Property formatted As String
    Public Property address_line1 As String
    Public Property address_line2 As String

    Public Property plus_code_short As String

    Public Property plus_code As String

    Public Property result_type As String
    Public Property rank As String
    Public Property place_id As String
End Class
```

I just don't know why it shows me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your AutoCompleteResponse class expects "features" to be a string, but in your json "feature" is much more complex than just a string. To reflect the complexity of the data of "feature" in your code, you need to make a class for it. Then in the AutoCompleteResponse class, features will be a list of these classes.

Here's how the feature class could look:

```
Public Class Feature
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property geometry As Geometry
    Public Property properties As Properties
End Class
```